# In container built with quarkus, trying to optionally enable OIDC integration with keycloak on docker container start

Tags: docker, quarkus, quarkus-oidc

i would like to provide our container with an optional OIDC/keycloak integration, disabled by default but possible to enable when starting a container via env variables.

This is how the configuration looks like in application.properties at build time:

```
quarkus.oidc.enabled=false
# quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=<auth-server-url>
# quarkus.oidc.client-id=<client-id>
# quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=<secret>
```

Ideally, on container start, `quarkus.oidc.enabled=true` could be set along side the other three properties via container env variables.

However, quarkus won't allow this, as `quarkus.oidc.enabled` can only be set on build time apparently, but not overridden at runtime (https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect#configuring-the-application).

I have found a google group that picks up on this topic (https://groups.google.com/g/quarkus-dev/c/isGqZvY829g/m/BNerQvSRAQAJ), mentioning the use of `quarkus.oidc.tenant-enabled=false` instead, but i am not sure how to apply this strategy in my use case.

Can anyone help me out here on how to make this work without having to build two images (one with oidc enabled, and one without) ?

Comment: As you mention, the `quarkus.oidc.enabled` configuration property is a **build-time** configuration property, meaning that you cannot change it when starting the application. So you would have to build two different versions of the application

Comment: do you think a feature (improvement) request for offering this functionality would be feasible? @geoand

Comment: I would suggest opening a Github discussion